# pyqt5 permanent widget focus

Tags: pyqt

in my pyqt5 application, I have a QLineEdit that can have its value changed by both typing and pressing buttons that have advanced actions on the QLineEdit's text.

I have done some research and found the setFocusPolicy, but it does not have a permanent focus option, is there a way around this?

edit: by "permanent focus" I mean that the QLineEdit is always in a focus state where one can type into it, but clicking somewhere else or tabbing does not change the focus to a different widget

Comment: What do you mean by "permanent focus"?

Comment: The only way is to set the focus policy to `NoFocus` to *all* other widgets that might receive focus: buttons, text fields, comboboxes, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[musicamante](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2001654/musicamante) had it right, what I did was add a corresponding `*widgetObject*.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)` line for each of my widgets that could possibly focus

note: I had this import line specifically for the NoFocus constant

`from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt`